# Problem uploading to board error, but I've selected the port and the board type?

Tags: arduino-uno

I am having an issue when I try to upload a program to the board. I am working on a Simon Says game, and when I first started uploading, my computer handled it fine. Everything worked properly.

However, now I have added 3 LEDs for the colors and 3 buttons. I wrote a program for them to start the game, and then went to test it. That's when my Arduino would beep 3 times and then 75% of the time my computer would give me this error:

> Problem uploading to board.
>   See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.

25% of the other time I get this:

> An error occurred while uploading the sketch

It seems as though my project is getting too complicated for the Arduino to handle maybe? This is my code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);

int s = 13; // Speaker
int r = 6;  // Red LED
int y = 5;  // Yellow LED
int g = 4;  // Green LED
int b1 = 3; // Red button
int b2 = 2; // Yellow button
int b3 = 1; // Green button - I don't know if pin 1 works.

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  pinMode(s, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(r, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(y, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(g, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(b1, INPUT);
  pinMode(b2, INPUT);
  // pinMode(b3, INPUT); Does pin 1 work?
}

void loop() {
  lcd.print("Press any button");
  lcd.setCursor(4, 1);
  lcd.print("to play!");
  while (true) {
    if (digitalRead(b1) == HIGH) {
      break;
    }
    delay(50);
  }
  lcd.clear();
  delay(1000);
  lcd.setCursor(1, 0);
  lcd.print("Simon's turn!");
  delay(1000);
  while (true) {
    // For now, I don't want to loop. I will finish the program when this     problem is resolved.
    delay(50);
  }
}
```

Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Comment: What precisely is wired to pin 1?

Comment: Pin 1 goes to the button which goes with the green LED. It can tell when the button is pressed. I didn't know if that was the problem, but when I commented it out, the upload still had an error (not in the code).

Comment: Anything *besides* the button? Any pullup or pulldown resistor?  If you *disconnect everything* from pin 1 does it start working again?

Comment: Let me try that.

Comment: Okay, I removed everything from pin 1, tried to upload again. Unfortunately, still an error. Also, there is nothing else other than the button.
*Edit*
There is a potentiometer, but it doesn't even connect to pin 1. It is for the LCD display adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

Arduino play around from time to time. Which one do you use.

Unplug it and plug it back in. If Pin D0 and D1 are occupied, you may have problems with uploading.

Comment: I use the Uno. I have unplugged and plugged back in, that didn't affect anything. Pin D0 and D1 are not occupied. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Something is blocking the port. It is not a compiler error.

Comment: Can you upload other scripts. Or is it only happen on this one?

Comment: It only happens with this one, which is strange. I've started a new file and it works fine.

Comment: Hi Ben. Sorry. I was a little bit busy. I am glad you resolve your problem by creating a new file. I work in IT Support. I also like to know why something is causing the problems. I may have a look at it at some point. Sorry. Just very busy now, with my Arduino projects. I may come across a similar problem and then I will post the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Remove anything that is connected to the Tx and Rx pin(communication pins)

And try uploading the code and it might possibly work